# Unable to calculate Random Effects Model in with lmer4 because variables are non-numeric

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I want to calculate a linear mixed model in which:

```
y = frequency of a correct response (in column "answers_correct" = "True")
x = condition benevolent (in column "condition_benevolent" = "True")
```

True in x means that the experimental condition was benevolent and false means that the experimental conditions were either malignant or random. The graph may help to understand the data.

[image]

I appreciate any help!! In the following my tries....

```
#Linear mixed model benevolent

#data_with_id$condition_benevolent_numeric <- recode(data_with_id$condition_benevolent, "False"  = 0, "True" = 1)               

#n <- 480
x <- c(data_with_id$condition_benevolent)
data_with_id$condition_benevolent <- as.numeric(data_with_id$condition_benevolent == "A")
view(data_with_id$condition_benevolent)

x <- model.matrix(~x -1, data = data_with_id, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)[,-1] #dummycodierung, True=1
#frequ <- häufigkeit_richtig_df_benev

y <- data_with_id$answers_correct

model_H1.1_benevolent <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|trial), data=data_with_id) 
summary(model_H1.1_benevolent)

length(y)
length(x)
length(data_with_id$trial)
view(y)
view(x)
nrow(data_with_id)
nrow(data_with_id$condition_benevolent)
nrow(data_with_id$trial)
```

Comment: Since these are count data you may want to consider poisson or negative binomial regression (or their zero inflated analogues). These use discrete distributions and are more appropriate for count data compared to a linear model with an assumption that the outcome is normally distributed (continuous)

Comment: While I agree with @jpsmith that you should consider an alternative to model count data, I just wanted to point out that the assumption with a linear model is not that the outcome is normally distributed, but that the residuals are

Comment: @sjp is correct I mistakenly said outcome - good catch - thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Im trying my luck with random effects logistic regression model atm.